# How to use the name of an existing dict for creating new dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionaries named `Bgf`, `Arf` and so on which have multiple `dataframes` in them.

I am now creating a function that takes the name of the dictionary as a parameter by the user and then isolates `dataframes` whose names end with '_with_lof' in that dataframe. Now the `dfs` that are isolated must be stored in a new empty dict and the dict must have a name format as follows: `'dictionary'_filtered.`

**For example:**

the dictionary `Bgf` has the following `dfs`:

```
s24_df
s25_df
s26_df
s27_df
dataframes
merged_df
s7_with_lof
s1_with_lof
```

Now, I want to isolate the `dfs` whose name contain the string `_with_lof`. Here s7_with_lof & s1_with_lof match. Now these two `dfs` must be stored a new dictionary whose name must be `Bgf_filtered`.

Similary, if the user gives `Arf` as the parameter, then the new dictionary name must be `Arf_filtered`.

**My code:**

```
def filtered(dictionary):
    filter_string = '_with_lof'
    **dictionary**_filtered = {k: v for (k, v) in Bgf.items() if filter_string in k}
```

Now, when the user does:

```
filtered('Bgf')
```

the `Bgf` must be used in the third line of the function for creating the new dict as `Bgf_filtered`.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: creating variable names dynamically is really bad idea. IMHO you should rethink your setup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: even though this is a bad idea, you can use `exec('varName = yourDataForTheVar')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing smells of bad code, creating new variables like that isn't normal. And anyone who reads your code after you will curse you for it.

But still, you can do something like this:

```
def filtered(dictionary_name):
    filter_string = '_with_lof'
    globals()["%s_filtered" % (dictionary_name)] = {k: v for (k, v) in globals()[dictionary_name].items() if filter_string in k}
```

Normal code would be however, something that would return the filtered dictionary:

```
def filtered(dictionary):
    filter_string = '_with_lof'
    return {k: v for (k, v) in dictionary.items() if filter_string in k}
```

And then used like:

```
Bgf_filtered = filtered(Bgf)
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I am following the normal way now. I am not creating the variables dynamically. Thanks for your help